# Loop only works when i'm in the worksheet i'm using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

sorry for the rookie question - i'm just starting on vba.

i have the below code, which only works when i am actually on the worksheet called 'position details'. the workbook has multiple worksheets but the code doesn't work if i'm in any of the other sheet. i am not 100% sure why as i've tried referencing the worksheet i want the code to run in in multiple ways. i think it's getting stuck on the line i've put in bold below.

i would like to be able to run the code from any worksheet, if that's possible.

any help greatly appreciated.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Position detail").Columns("p").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Worksheets(2).Columns("w:aa").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Worksheets(2).Range("AA:AA").EntireColumn.Insert

Worksheets("Position detail").Range("aa2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=RC[-1],""BAD"",""GOOD"")"
**Worksheets("Position detail").Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow).FillDown**

Dim CTH As Range

For Each CTH In Worksheets(2).Range(Range("AA2"), Range("AA2").End(xlDown))
If CTH = "GOOD" Then CTH.Interior.Color = vbGreen Else CTH.Interior.Color = vbRed

Next CTH
```

Comment: You need to qualify the worksheet/workbook that `Range("AA2")` and `Range("AA2").End(xlDown)` are on/in within the loop.

Comment: Btw, `Worksheets(2)` could be a dangerous way of qualification... =)

Comment: Suggest qualifying with the `Codename` in lieu of sheet (tab) name and as @jvdV says, using the index (in this case) is dangerous. The index is based on where the sheet is in relation to the other sheets. Users can break your code by renaming the tab, or by moving the worksheet.

Comment: thank you all for your responses, very much appreciated.